# Swift - Cast object that inheritances from that class

Tags: inheritance, casting, swift

I'm getting this error: Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type $'T5'
PlayingCard inheritance from Card, and I know that the drawRandomCard returns a PlayingCard.
How can I make this conversion?

```
var deck = PlayingCardDeck()
var card = PlayingCard()

class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func cardTouchBtn(sender : UIButton) {

    if !sender.currentTitle{sender.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)}
    if  sender.currentTitle.isEmpty{
        card = PlayingCard(deck.drawRandomCard())
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named : "cardFront"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setTitle(card.contents, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else{
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named : "cardBack"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

}
```

full code on git: https://github.com/victoryudi/CS193p-Swift/tree/master/FlipCard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PlayingCard(...)` is not a cast. It's a constructor call.

If you want to cast, use `deck.drawRandomCard() as PlayingCard`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed on that. Thank you!